# Java implement schema and row interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am implementing an in-memory table library. I have a ITableSchema interface that defines the columns, table name etc. I also have a IRow interface with methods like get(Column), set(Column). What would be a good practice way to ensure that. If I have Say Two table schemas TableA, TableB and a row implementation for each schema- what would be a good way to ensure RowAs are not used with TableBs etc. can I use templates for this somehow?

Comment: Hi, please check [ask] to avoid downvotes and close votes. Also long story shory, use JPA, you will not have to even think of such things as those are enforced by design.

Comment: A few options.  Have an `IRow` interface and a `boolean contains(IRow row);` method on your `ITableSchema` interface, and then have each `Table*` class check against an internal `List` of the appropriate `IRow`s.  Add a generic `Itable` or similar to the `IRow` which specifies _which_ `Table*` that `IRow` can be used with.  Just specify in the documentation.  Or don't worry about it, since you might come up with rows which want to be used across multiple tables in the future.